# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie

Tags: cookies, forms-authentication

hi we are using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(profile.Id, false);`

Now the question is when does this cookie expires?

It of course expires once I close all the browsers but it doesn't I keep the browser open and I don't know the timelimit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the [Timeout](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/08/430011.aspx) property in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

In the system.web attribute of your web.config file, you must set the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

then your cookie will expire depending on the value you have set in the timeout attribute.